# jq: nesting objects according to two keys

Tags: jq

Here my documents:

```json
{
   "name":"name1",
   "oid1":"oid1-1",
   "oid2":"oid2-1"
}{
   "name":"name2",
   "oid1":"oid1-2",
   "oid2":"oid2-2"
}
```

By other side:

```json
{
  "id": "id1",
  "info": "info1",
  "oid1":"oid1-1",
  "oid2":"oid2-1"
}
{
  "id": "id2",
  "info": "info2",
  "oid1":"oid1-1",
  "oid2":"oid2-1"
}
{
  "id": "id3",
  "info": "info3",
  "oid1":"oid1-2",
  "oid2":"oid2-2"
}
```

I need to nest just above documents into first ones:

```json
{
   "name":"name1",
   "oid1":"oid1-1",
   "oid2":"oid2-1",
   "ids":[
      {
         "id":"id1",
         "info":"info1"
      },
      {
         "id":"id2",
         "info":"info2"
      }
   ]
}{
   "name":"name2",
   "oid1":"oid1-2",
   "oid2":"oid2-2",
   "ids":[
      {
         "id":"id3",
         "info":"info3"
      }
   ]
}
```

So, I need to nest into first documents, which ones `parent.oid1 == nest.oid1 && parent.oid2 == nest.oid2`.

I've not been to get anything reasonable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "my documents" is stored in a file called `mine.json` and the "other side" is the contents of a file `others.json`, then `--slurpfile` the others and add them based on a `select`:

```sh
jq --slurpfile others others.json '
  . as $mine
  | . + {ids: ($others | map(          
    select(.oid1 == $mine.oid1 and .oid2 == $mine.oid2)
    | {id, info}
  ))}
' mine.json
```

```json
{
  "name": "name1",
  "oid1": "oid1-1",
  "oid2": "oid2-1",
  "ids": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "info": "info1"
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "info": "info2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "name2",
  "oid1": "oid1-2",
  "oid2": "oid2-2",
  "ids": [
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info3"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BGysVRwxmI) (using an object with fields `mine` and `others` instead of files)